# Get arrival time without departure time

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-distancematrix-api

I am trying to get the travel time to a certain destination based on the time of arrival. It is available through Google Maps, But the API seems to force to enter a departure time... which I don't know. I just know the expected time of arrival.

yet...

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&traffic_model=best_guess&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&arrival_time=1505894400&key=MY-KEY

RETURNS:
{
   "destination_addresses" : [],
   "error_message" : "Invalid request. Missing the 'departure_time' parameter.",
   "origin_addresses" : [],
   "rows" : [],
   "status" : "INVALID_REQUEST"
}

Any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `&traffic_model=best_guess`:

This works for me:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=Vancouver+BC|Seattle&destinations=San+Francisco|Victoria+BC&arrival_time=1505894400&key=MY-KEY
```